# mql4 trying to use iMAOnArray to generate smoothed moving average on a calculated value

Tags: mql4

I'm trying to convert a piece of code written in Pinescript into mql4. The pine code is this:

```
out=(close-low)*100/(high-low)
ma=ta.sma(out,12)
ma2=ta.sma(ma,6)
```

In this three lines I get
Line 1: a series that contains the close as a percentage of bar height.
Line 2: a moving average over the percentage values
Line 3: a smoothing of the moving average

How can I achieve the same thing in mql4? I expect I have to use iMAOnArray but I'm not sure.

Can anyone give some pointers?

I have tried starting off with something like this, but not sure from there. I could go back to basics and do the entire ma in code, but there must be an easier way.

```
   double pct[maLength*2];
   for (int i=0;i<maLength*2;i++)
   {
      pct[i]=(Close[i+1]-Low[i+1])*100/(High[i+1]-Low[i+1])
   }
```